# EXEC within the TRY...CATCH block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to drop all the tables in the database with the following script:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0)
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
END
```

I am getting lots of errors because of the foreign key constraints. But that is fine, tables are dropped anyway. I would like to get rid of the error messages with the following script.

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?';
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  END CATCH
END
```

This script just runs forever trying to drop the first table.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your query, but I've dropped tables using a cursor like this:

```
DECLARE @name as varchar(100)
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT name FROM sys.tables 

OPEN MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    execute('drop table ' +@name)

 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @name
END

CLOSE MyCursor 
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't it still suffer from the foreign key constraints?